# Flutter ExpansionTile with map using groupBy in list

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, listview, group-by

I'm trying to make the ExpansionTile widget works with a map created from a List.
Here is what my code looks like:

```
  class School{
  final String classname;
  final String section;
  final String alumnNumber;

  School({required this.classname, required this.section, required this.alumnNumber}); }

  final List<School> schoolList =
  [ 
    School(classname: "test1", section: "A", alumnNumber: 20),
    School(classname: "test2", section: "B", alumnNumber: 10),    
    School(classname: "test3", section: "C", alumnNumber: 15),
    School(classname: "test4", section: "B", alumnNumber: 16),
    School(classname: "test5", section: "A", alumnNumber: 22),
    School(classname: "test6", section: "D", alumnNumber: 25),
    School(classname: "test7", section: "A", alumnNumber: 24),
    School(classname: "test8", section: "A", alumnNumber: 21),
  ]
```

This will be my starting point. I want to regroup this list so items with same 'section' would be collapsed together.

```
final sectionGroup =groupBy(schoolList, (obj) => (obj as School).section);
```

If I try to print my sectionGroup it seems to work

```
{A: [Instance of 'School',Instance of 'School',Instance of 'School',Instance of 'School'], B: [Instance of 'School',Instance of 'School'], C: [Instance of 'School'], D: [Instance of 'School']}
```

What I want to do is to show this in an ExpansionTile Widget but nothing seems to work. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sectionGroup` is providing map with `section` and `List<School>`.

You can iterate the map/values like

```dart
final sectionGroup = groupBy(schoolList, (obj) => (obj as School).section);

class GExpMar extends StatelessWidget {
  const GExpMar({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: sectionGroup.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final key = sectionGroup.keys.elementAt(index);
          final values = sectionGroup.values.elementAt(index);
          return ExpansionTile(
            title: Text("$key"),
            children: values
                .map(
                  (e) => ListTile(
                    // you can use Column or other widget
                    title: Text("${e.classname}"),
                    subtitle: Text("${e.alumnNumber}"),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```